# jdbc.ConnectionImpl.buildCollationMapping throw a ClassCastException

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

1. I use the Tomcat v8.0.39, mysql8, jdk1.8, mybatis v3.2.8.
2. when I first get connection with DB, the class com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
   in mysql-connector-java-5.1.26.jar throw a ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
3. I try to make a breakpoint to check, the code:

   ```
   private void buildCollationMapping() throws SQLException {

   HashMap<Integer, String> javaCharset = null;

   if (versionMeetsMinimum(4, 1, 0)) {

       TreeMap<Long, String> sortedCollationMap = null;
       HashMap<Integer, String> customCharset = null;
       HashMap<String, Integer> customMblen = null;

       if (getCacheServerConfiguration()) {
           synchronized (serverCollationByUrl) {
               sortedCollationMap = (TreeMap<Long, String>) serverCollationByUrl.get(getURL());
               javaCharset = (HashMap<Integer, String>) serverJavaCharsetByUrl.get(getURL());
               customCharset = (HashMap<Integer, String>) serverCustomCharsetByUrl.get(getURL());
               customMblen = (HashMap<String, Integer>) serverCustomMblenByUrl.get(getURL());
           }
       }

       java.sql.Statement stmt = null;
       java.sql.ResultSet results = null;

       try {
           if (sortedCollationMap == null) {
               sortedCollationMap = new TreeMap<Long, String>();
               javaCharset = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
               customCharset = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
               customMblen = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

               stmt = getMetadataSafeStatement();

               try {
                   results = stmt.executeQuery("SHOW COLLATION");
                   if (versionMeetsMinimum(5, 0, 0)) {
                       Util.resultSetToMap(sortedCollationMap, results, 3, 2);
                   } else {
                       while (results.next()) {
                           sortedCollationMap.put(results.getLong(3), results.getString(2));
                       }
                   }
               } catch (SQLException ex) {
                   if (ex.getErrorCode() != MysqlErrorNumbers.ER_MUST_CHANGE_PASSWORD || getDisconnectOnExpiredPasswords()) {
                       throw ex;
                   }
               }

               for (Iterator<Map.Entry<Long, String>> indexIter = sortedCollationMap.entrySet().iterator(); indexIter.hasNext();) {
                   Map.Entry<Long, String> indexEntry = indexIter.next();

                   int collationIndex = indexEntry.getKey().intValue();
   ```

when step to the "int collationIndex = indexEntry.getKey().intValue();", it throw the ClassCastException.

is there anybody meet before, how to fix it? thanks...

Comment: `sortedCollationMap.put(results.getLong(3), results.getString(2));`this line doesn't throw this exception ? what date type `getLong(3)` is in your database?

Comment: versionMeetsMinimum(5, 0, 0) == true
and Util.resultSetToMap(sortedCollationMap, results, 3, 2);
doesn't throw any exception.

Comment: just catch ClassClastException and print stack trace to the console ,give us this message.

Comment: `} catch (RuntimeException ex) {
    SQLException sqlEx = SQLError.createSQLException(ex.toString(), SQLError.SQL_STATE_ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT, null);
    sqlEx.initCause(ex);
    throw sqlEx;
   } `

Comment: Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

Comment: Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

Comment: no, do not throw any exception use `System.out.println(e.printStackTrace())` if in your catch statement you defined Exception named e;just give us what you IDE console display when Exception happened

Comment: I know does it show the exception comes from which line in your ide?

Comment: I have solved it through change Tomcat 8.039 to Tomcat 8.0.43.

Comment: Congratuation to you.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of an old question but we tackled the same thing yesterday. It turned out to be due to the fact we were using MySQL v8 but the my sql connector was v5. When MySQL v5 was installed the issue went away.

Check your database and connector versions to ensure compatibility.